# how to can i to get this string from text file

Tags: sed, awk

i can read this format text(e.g. id.txt) file:

```
 - 1BCF-2982 -- Installing Driver
 - 1BCF-2982 -- Driver Installed
 - (Testing Wireless 5630 (EVDO-HSPA) Mobile Broadband Mini-Card)
 - Executing Test -- MEID hex value
 - Extended test data -- MEID:0xA1000013B8F66E
 - Executing Test -- IMEI decimal value
 - Extended test data -- IMEI:355023040845227
 - Executing Test -- ICCID decimal value
 - (Wireless 5630 (EVDO-HSPA) Mobile Broadband Mini-Card Test Results)
```

or below format id.txt file

```
 - 1BCF-2982 -- Installing Driver
 - 1BCF-2982 -- Driver Installed
 - (Testing Wireless 5630 (EVDO-HSPA) Mobile Broadband Mini-Card)
 - Extended test data -- MEID:0xA1000013B8F66E
 - Extended test data -- IMEI:355023040845227
 - (Wireless 5630 (EVDO-HSPA) Mobile Broadband Mini-Card Test Results)
```

this is my way, build meid.sed and imei.sed

```
/MEID/{
s/^.*:0x([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/set meid=\1/p;
}
```

and imei.sed

```
/IMEI/{
s/^.*:([-0-9a-zA-Z]+)/set imei=\1/p;
}
```

Could you talk me simple way, the output will look like this:

```
set meid=A1000013B8F66E
set imei=355023040845227
```

thanks!

Comment: So what's wrong with your current method (`meid.sed` and `imei.sed`)?

Comment: i can get i want but i think this complicated

Answer (score 3):

```
$ sed -nr '/.*(MEID|IMEI):(0x)?([0-9A-F]+)/s//set \L\1\E=\3/p' id.txt
set meid=A1000013B8F66E
set imei=355023040845227
```

Answer (score 2):

dirty and quick awk oneliner works with your examples:

```
awk -F' -- |:' 'NF>2{print "set "tolower($2)"="$3}' yourFile
```

test with example1:

```
kent$  echo "- 1BCF-2982 -- Installing Driver
 - 1BCF-2982 -- Driver Installed
 - (Testing Wireless 5630 (EVDO-HSPA) Mobile Broadband Mini-Card)
 - Extended test data -- MEID:0xA1000013B8F66E
 - Extended test data -- IMEI:355023040845227
 - (Wireless 5630 (EVDO-HSPA) Mobile Broadband Mini-Card Test Results)
"|awk -F' -- |:' 'NF>2{print "set "tolower($2)"="$3}'
set meid=0xA1000013B8F66E
set imei=355023040845227
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same with this command

```
cat <your input file> | grep -E "MEID:|IMEI:" | awk '{print $NF;}' | tr ':' '=' | awk '{print "set " $0;}'
```

either you can run it from command prmpt or put the same in .sh file and run it

Comment: output "set MEID=0xA1000013B8F66E set IMEI=355023040845227" but i can get "set MEID=A1000013B8F66E set IMEI=355023040845227"

Comment: I am not clear what u are asking for. With my above script the output is set MEID=0xA1000013B8F66E
set IMEI=355023040845227             . Whats your expected output

Comment: i hope this script output is "set MEID=A1000013B8F66E set IMEI=355023040845227", thanks!

Comment: Holy cow, this is massively overcomplicated.